# Android ignoring font-style:italic in CSS code

Tags: android, html, css

I have a simple line of text

```
<h4>This is just some placeholder junk</h4>
```

with the following CSS:

```
h4 {
    font-size:20px;
    color:#000000;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

This is working in everything but the default browser on Android GS3.

I've tried wrapping the text in a span with `font-style:italic;`, as well as including `<i>` and `<em>` tags, but the font will not slant. Am I overlooking something simple here?

Comment: The default font on a lot of Android phones doesn't have an italic version.  Try setting a specific font that you know italicizes.

Comment: Exactly what Gabe said, but in addition, if it's an imported font, make sure you're importing the italic version of the font as well.

Comment: @GabeSechan That should be an answer

Comment: ahhh okay, i didn't know android was like that. thanks!

Comment: @NOPENOPENOPE Did the custom font work for you?

Comment: yep, it looks good now

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance I would not recommend to use a custom font on mobile devices at all, unless there is really no other way. But this seems to be a problem caused by Samsung: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=169446#c11

So I think this is one of the rare situations where you should go with a custom font. Of course it should be a custom font that *supports* the italic font style. Don´t forget the `font-style`property in the `@font-face` declaration.

```
@font-face {
  ...
  font-style: italic, oblique;
}
```